# Real time video processing in android? like in Google I/O 2018. with openCV what frame rate achievable>

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, computer-vision

Though this topic has been discussed several time in this forum.

This year at google I/O CEO Sundar showed one remarkable video

https://youtu.be/ogfYd705cRs?t=1h26m52s

Though it is difficult to predict but what they might have used? openCV?

To me openCV will be too slow to operate, if the processing is done in mobile phone itself. Is their any other way through NDK or sth else?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [ARCore](https://developers.google.com/ar/), that demo is using this library.